# How to reset or clear user profile in Windows 10 from command line?

Tags: windows, domain, user, profile

I'll have to use shared user profile which is on Domain. I would like to clear/reset the profile to default settings so it will be like a new profile when user logs in. How can I do this from command line?

Comment: I do not think you can do this. Users should have their own domain profiles and not shared.

Comment: You soon run out of disk space if every one use their own profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used DelProf2 https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/ . Normally I delete all profiles except few profiles I want to keep. With /id: you can delete only one specifig profile.

```
DelProf2.exe /l /id:username

   /l   List only, do not delete (what-if mode)
   /u   Unattended (no confirmation)
   /id  Include only profile directories whose name matches this pattern
        Wildcard characters * and ? can be used in the pattern
        May be used more than once and can be combined with /ed
```